# Mail generated from php is not formatted in outlook, but looks perfect on Iphone mail

Tags: php, ios, outlook

I have some php code that read data from an informix database, put that data into an html table, and send a mail with the html in the message.

When someone uses outlook to read the mail, the mail appears like this:
 https://ibb.co/X3vRzB3

When someone uses iphone mail app the email looks like this:
https://ibb.co/VxdsLnF

the strangest thing is that if someone forward the email from iphone to outlook the email is properly formatted like it was on the iphone.

I would expect that the email generated is showed in the same way in outlook as it is shown in iphone mail program.

I tried adding

```
$msg .= "<div id= \" main \" style= \"color: white; \">";
```

to the php code before the creation of the table and closing the div after the table is closed, but outlook is still showing the email like before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. I had two while loops. One fetching records and one adding a table for every "cliente" but not closing it. At the beginning there was only one table. Now I'm closing the table and opening again every time "cliente" changes. Doing that formats the email properly. I still don't know why mail for iOS was correcting the format. Outlook was showing exactly what arrived in the mail.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in formatting your CSS code for emails. It should be built in your tags like this:

```
<div style="color: red;">
```

I guess IOS application has its own algorithm to process CSS part, not like Outlook.

Comment: I tried, edited the answer accordingly, nothing changed.